# How to Add Button on Last Page in Carousel view using xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, view, carousel

I want to add a Button in Last page in CarouselView page any one can help me ?

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sing"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="sing.Welcome"
    BackgroundColor="#ff4949">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:Items/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
```

Here is my Carousel view with Binding items in my ViewModels

```cs
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                      IndicatorView="indicatorView">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame HasShadow="False"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               Margin="0,50,0,0"
                               HeightRequest="300"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               BackgroundColor="#ff4949">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                                       HeightRequest="300"
                                       WidthRequest="300"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

Continuation :::::::

```cs
        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                       IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                       IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                       SelectedIndicatorColor="Yellow"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Margin="0,0,0,40" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Is it possible to Add a button on last page?

Comment: Can you get the last position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the Button in **DataTemplate** in advance . And set the property **IsVisible** as true of the last item .

#### in xaml

```
<DataTemplate>

    <StackLayout>

          <Frame HasShadow="False"
                 CornerRadius="5"
                 Margin="0,50,0,0"
                 HeightRequest="300"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 BackgroundColor="#ff4949">
             <StackLayout>
                 <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                                       HeightRequest="300"
                                       WidthRequest="300"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
             </StackLayout>
         </Frame>

         <Button Text="xxx" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"/>

    </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

#### in your model

```
public class xxxModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    bool isVisible=false;   // the button is invisible in default

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            if (isVisible != value)
            {
                isVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
    }

    //other properties
}
```

#### in ViewModel

invoke the following line after you initialize the **ItemSource**

```
var model = Monkeys[Monkeys.Count - 1] as xxxModel;

model.IsVisible = true;
```